# How can I mediate a multipart message in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have to mediate a multipart message in a API resource, so that, at first I have to call virus scan service and depending on the response:

- If the response is 200 OK continue.
- Else, the response is 401 Unauthorized drop message and return 401 response.

I have tired drop message (due to limitations in measuring multipart messages) if I get 401 in mediation, but the original message always go on.

Is there any solutions for that? Is possible mediate message with Java class mediator?

Is there any way to drop parent message by messageID?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple `<drop/>` in your sequence, the message shouldn't be processed further. How does your API/Proxy look like?

You can also process your message inside your custom Java class. See the following link for an example.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java